# Template Haskell resolve type aliases

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm using template Haskell to generate data about a type. For many reasons I need the type to be used to be "normalized". So it shouldn't be a type alias/synonym. I really don't want to disallow using type aliases in the construct since some types that are used can become huge.

So now I have the problem that when a user specifies a type it doesn't match the type I expect. For example if I have this definition:

```
data MyData a = MyData Int

type Foo = MyData String Int Bool

serializeMyData :: TH.Type -> TH.Q [TH.Dec]
serializeMyData ty = ..

type Foo = MyData Int
```

And then later in I call this `serializeMyData` like this:

```
$(serializeMyData =<< [t| Foo |] )
```

Then in the `serializeMyData` it will find a `ConT Foo`. This is correct since the user has specified the type alias. But is not useable for me.

So my question is how can I resolve type aliases?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`resolveTypeSynonyms :: TH.Type -> Q TH.Type`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/th-abstraction-0.4.3.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Datatype.html#v:resolveTypeSynonyms) can be found in the library [th-abstraction](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/th-abstraction).